# I want to display a specific cookie(s) into an input using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

So I want to have a responsive page that displays cookies. I want the values of the function to display on load of the page within the input value, but I've only been able to display it using an onclick function.  here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     function readCookie(FullName) {
       var name = FullName + "=";
       var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
       for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
         var c = ca[i];
         while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
         if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
       }
       return "";
     }

</script>

<label>First Name from cookie: <input id="name2" maxlength="25" name="namefield" readonly="readonly" size="20" type="text" /> </label> 

<input onclick="document.getElementById('name2').value = readCookie('FullName')" type="submit" value="Get cookie" />
```

How do I get the function to display the result within the input without using a submit button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a `<script>` element after that `<input>` with the content of submit button's `onclick` attribute:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     function readCookie(FullName) {
       var name = FullName + "=";
       var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
       for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
         var c = ca[i];
         while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
         if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
       }
       return "";
     }

</script>

<label>First Name from cookie: <input id="name2" maxlength="25" name="namefield" readonly="readonly" size="20" type="text" /> </label> 

<script>
  document.getElementById('name2').value = readCookie('FullName')
</script>
```

Comment: How would I display the cookie as a normal piece of text within the label? Not as an input?